# Is there a way to prevent VS Code from showing usings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using a VS Code

in file A I have defined

```
using GPSFlatRoute = std::vector<cv::Point2f>;
```

and, at least in that file VS Code shows something aka
[image: code snippet with definition]

which is totally ok by me.

However, in the other file B it hints, that vector of points is a GPS route, which, specifically where, is not the case.
[image: code snippet with intellisense problem highlighted]

Is it possible to shut off this reverse detection of using? Telling what is behind the using - is ok, the other way around is almost always wrong.

Comment: Scrap the official C++ intellisense and replace it with Clangd?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Unfortunately, I'm running the Code from inside the docker and installing [clangd server] is not gonna work.

Comment: *"is not gonna work"* What do you mean? Can you perhaps connect a natively running VSC to the docker (there was a 'remote development' extension for that).

Comment: eventually, my dev environment should resemble 1-1 the environment in deployment. + maintenance team installed something, so installations are not working, i.e. you need to uninstall a required component just to fix the issue.

Comment: ... maybe installing clangd server locally on my machine, outside the docker, is meant?

Comment: Possibly controversial opinion: IntelliSense is rubbish and should be switched off.

Comment: @dEmigOd Launching Clangd plugin is going to ask if you want to install Clangd. Did you get any errors when clicking "yes"? I think it's going to install it internally, without exposing it to PATH, so similarity with prod shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, it "runs" install. asks to reload, suggests to install, then claims it is already installed. in a loop

Comment: Nice. :( Ask the maintenance team.